# Uniform or absolute convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^2+n^2}{n^3}$ in interval $[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Uniform or absolute convergence  of

> $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^2+n^2}{n^3}$

**solution i tried**-The given sequence is  $\displaystyle(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^2+n^2}{n^3}$

lets take $b_n=\displaystyle\frac{1}{n }\;\;so \;\;\frac{a_n}{b_n}$
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{\frac{x^2+n^2}{n^3}}{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac {n(x^2+n^2)}{n^3}$$
$$=n^3\frac{(\frac{x^2}{n^2}+1)}{n^3}$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{x^2}{n^2}+1)=1 $$

which is finite so given series is not absolutly convergent.because $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$

But i am not getting idea about unifrom convergence, i tried $M_n$ test Abel's test Dirichlet's test but geeting no where

Please help

Comment: For your curiosity, the summation is $\log (2)+\frac{3}{4}  \zeta (3) x^2$

Comment: there is alternate negative and positive signs how you managed them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It converges uniformly by [Abel's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test#Abel's_uniform_convergence_test): the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n$ converges uniformly and the sequence $\left(\frac{x^2+n^2}{n^2}\right)_{n\in\mathbb Z_+}$ is an uniformly bounded decreasing sequence of functions.

Comment: The domain of $x^2$ is $[-1,1]$ in Which $x^2$ is neither increasing nor decreasing but according to Abel's condition the sequence should monotonic.As according to you here $\frac{x^2}{n^2}+1$ is decreasing but this is will same sequence for both $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{-1}{2}$

Comment: ok got it ,the sequence is of form ${x^2+1,\frac{x^2}{4}+4,\frac{x^2}{9}+9...}$ which is sequence of upward parabolas which converges to line $y=1$ am i right sir?

Comment: @TheStudent Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate out $\sum (-1)^{n-1} \frac  1n$ (which is convergent) . The question reduces to uniform convergence of $\sum (-1)^{n-1} \frac {x^{2}} {n^{3}}$ and this series converges uniformly and absolutely by M-Test since $\sum \frac  1 {n^{3}} <\infty$.

Comment: This one is very quick method to solve this question ,Thank you.